# python scrape ajax content

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'd like to parse website with rates but i couldn't take out data from `<td>` elements.

I wrote short code to test which gets 1st line with data tabel:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.gpw.pl/wskazniki_spolek_full')
table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='tab03']/tbody/tr")[4].text
print table

driver.quit()
```

and i'm getting results:

`2 PLNFI0800016 141 08OCTAVA 42 786 848 44,07 63,86 2016-12-31 H 0,69 27,80 ---`

but i'd like go through all `<td>` elements in `<tr>` tag in loop by all tables which has `class='tab03'`

```
table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='tab03']/tbody/tr")

for el in table:
    col_id =  el.find_element_by_tag_name('td')[1].text
    col_kod = el.find_element_by_tag_name('td')[2].text

    print("{}".format(col_id, col_kod))

driver.quit()
```

but i'm getting error: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: td`

Answer (score 1):

There are some header rows that don't have `td` elements inside them, skip them:

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='tab03']/tbody/tr")

for row in rows[3:]:
    cells = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    col_id = cells[0].text
    col_kod = cells[1].text

    print("{}".format(col_id, col_kod))
```

Also note that, to get to the `td` cells, use the `find_elements_by_tag_name()` and get the desired elements by index (0-based).